# useState function seems to block Animated.timing event?

Tags: react-native

I've created a "twitter style" button that when pressed opens up a sub-menu of items that can be selected/"tweeted" about.

The button is simple in that when pressed, it triggers a function with Animated events:

```
  const toggleOpen = () => {
    if (this._open) {
      Animated.timing(animState.animation, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 300,
      }).start();
    } else {
      Animated.timing(animState.animation, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 300,
      }).start(); // putting '() => setFirstInteraction(true)' here causes RenderItems to disappear after the animation duration, until next onPress event.
    }
    this._open = !this._open;
  };
```

and here's the button that calls this function:

```
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => {
      toggleOpen();
      // setFirstInteraction(true); // this works here, but the button doesn't toggleOpen until the 3rd + attempt.
    }}>
    <Animated.View style={[
      styles.button, 
      styles.buttonActiveBg,
      ]}>
      <Image
        style={styles.icon}
        source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')}
      />
    </Animated.View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

I need to add a second `useState` function that is called at the same time as `toggleOpen();`. You can see my notes above regarding the problems I'm facing when using the `setFirstInteraction(true)` useState function I'm referring to.

Logically this should work, but for some reason when I add the `setFirstInteraction(true)` it seems to block the `toggleOpen()` function. If you persist and press the button a few times, eventually the `toggleOpen()` will work exactly as expected. My question is, why does this blocking type of action happen?

You can reproduce the issue in my snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@dazzerr/topicactionbutton-demo . Please use a device. The web preview presents no issues, but on both iOS and Android the issue is present. Line 191 is where you'll see the `setFirstInteraction(true)` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `animatedValue` isn't stable. This causes it to be recreated on each state change. It is advised to `useRef` instead (though, `useMemo` would do the trick here as well).

```js
const animState =  useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
```

Your `toggleOpen` function can also be simplified. In fact, you only need a single state to handle what you want and react on it in a `useEffect` to trigger the animations that you have implemented.

I have called this state `isOpen` and I have removed all other states. The `toggleOpen` function just toggles this state.

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

const toggleOpen = () => {
  setIsOpen(prev => !prev)
}
```

In the `useEffect` we react on state changes and trigger the correct animations.

```js
const animState =  useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('https://www.getfretwise.com/wp-json/buddyboss/v1/forums')
      .then(({ data }) => setData(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(animState, {
          toValue: isOpen ? 1 : 0,
          duration: 300,
          useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, [isOpen, animState])
```

I have adapted your snack. [Here is a working version](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/topicactionbutton-demo).

**Remarks:** Of course, you still need for your data to be fetched from your API. The opacity change of the button is still the same and it remains disabled until the data has been fetched.

Comment: This is excellent David thanks! Great thinking! However, as soon as isOpen returns false, the closing animation disappears. The closing animation doesn't work 

Comment: Ups, your animated value is not stable. It gets rebuild on each rerender

Comment: Check my updated answer and the new snack.

Comment: Master! Thank you, that now works perfectly. May I just ask for your clarification on why my initial `toggleOpen()` function was "wrong" so I can learn from my mistake?

Comment: I would've never thought to wrap the animState.animation in useMemo - thanks! And the ternary inside Animated.timing is much cleaner 

Comment: Actually, the `useMemo` is the root cause. The animation value is not stable in both implementations, thus setting `firstInteraction` sets the value back to `zero` on rerender. If you take your implementation and just `useMemo` on your animated value as I did in my answer, then it works as well.

Comment: @Dazza actually, this is better. I have updated my answer again. It is advised to `useRef` for animations. There is no need to use `useMemo` here. Animations should work as I have implemented them in the current version. Sorry, for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you kindly @David! That makes more sense yes, and is more consistent with other code I am working on. If you like ko-fi, I've just posted another question that would be blessed with your knowledge. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. Though, I am not an expert in animations, I'm afraid.